# How can I block communication between 2 interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, network-interface

I'm currently trying to develop a router application that applies/removes security wrappers to packets between two interfaces. The protocol is BACnet and it runs over UDP. The layout can be seen in the image here: [image: Layout]

For the most part, everything is working well. The router app can communicate with the controller and device simulator just fine. My issue comes into play when the router transmits broadcast packets (These are required by the BACnet spec). Any packets sent to 192.168.56.255 are received by 192.168.39.4, and all packets sent to 192.168.39.255 are received by 192.168.56.101.

This is not the behavior I was suspecting as they are on different subnets, so I'm assuming the linux kernel is doing some secret routing underneath my nose as I can't see anything in wireshark on interface enp0s8, enp0s9, or lo - I just see the packets arrive in the application layer of the router app.

I've disabled ipv4 forwarding (net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0 in sysctl) and I've tried messing with iptables forwarding, but that did nothing. I also ran "ip route show table local" and deleted local routes pertaining to my two interfaces - this stopped the broadcast packets from being received on the other interface, but prevented all communication with my host machine.

Is there a simple way to block all network traffic between two interfaces?

Comment: You can use vlans to segment a broadcast domain.